# Need of '$p$ is prime' in proof of Cauchy's theorem by McKay

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

This is outline of James McKay's [proof](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eyuvalf/McKay%20Another%20Proof%20of%20Cauchy%27s%20Group%20Theorem.pdf) of Cauchy's theorem by Dummit Foote Abstract Algebra:

[image]

> I need explanation for part (e), where they say: every equivalence class has order $1$ or $p$, and here they claim that $p$ is prime. But, I think that even if $p$ was not prime, every equivalence class would have order $1$ or $p$. For example, in $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, when we form similar $\mathcal S$, then tuples like $(2,2,2,2)$ have order $1$ but tuples like $(1,2,3,2)$ have order $4$. So, where do we use the fact that $p$ is prime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p=4$ you have tuples such as $(1,2,1,2)$ which have order $2$.

The point is that the cyclic group of order $p$ acts on the set of $p$-tuples
by cyclic permutations.
When $p$ is prime, the size of each orbit of this action is a factor of $p$,
so is $1$ or $p$. When $p$ is not prime, then one gets orbits whose size is
a proper factor of $p$, and the argument collapses.

Comment: $1+2+1+2=6$ is not $0$ mod 4

Comment: oh! 0,2,0,2 works